# Array of objects not sorted if I don't use map

Tags: javascript

Sorting this array of objects works if I map the objects first:

```js
let data = [{
    "date": "2018-07-31T00:00:00Z"
}, {
    date: undefined
}, {
    "date": "2020-07-01T00:00:00Z"
}, {
    "date": "2019-08-24T11:16:26Z"
}, {
    "date": "2011-11-19T00:00:00Z"
}]

let compare = (a, b) => {
    if (a < b) return 1;
    if (a > b) return -1;
    return 0

}

// Note: Use map first
let result = data.map(x=>x.date);
console.log(result.sort(compare))
```

But if I sort this array without mapping the objects first, sort doesn't work:

```js
let data = [{
    "date": "2018-07-31T00:00:00Z"
}, {
    date: undefined
}, {
    "date": "2020-07-01T00:00:00Z"
}, {
    "date": "2019-08-24T11:16:26Z"
}, {
    "date": "2011-11-19T00:00:00Z"
}]

// Similar compare function just adapted
let compare = (a, b) => {
    if (a.date < b.date) return 1;
    if (a.date > b.date) return -1;
    return 0

}

// Note: No map
let result = data;
console.log(result.sort(compare))
```

I can't see why this happens?

Comment: you're not sorting objects in the first code, you're sorting strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the object where the date is undefined. In the first example (with `.map()`), all the values are either strings or the one undefined. As per the specification of `Array.prototype.sort()`:

> "all undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no
> call to compareFunction"

([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

In the first example, the function is never called for the undefined value, so it is sorted last. In the second example, however, whenever you get `a.date` on the undefined value, you get undefined. Both `if`  statements in the sort function then resolve to `false` since `undefined` can't be less than or greater than a string. Therefore, 0 is continually returned for the following elements. The `undefined` remains in place and breaks the rest of the sorting.

Comment: That quote from the docs does seem to shed light, somehow I overlooked that.